# Remove string from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing an issue removing the string from the JSON response. I am using Javascript here.

Consider the following as my JSON response.

```
throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';
[
.
.

    JSON data
.
.
]
```

I want to remove "throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';" string from the Object and then I want that response so that I can access JSON data properly.

expected output after removing the string.

```
[
.
.

    JSON data
.
.
]
```

Comment: I think the real question is, why is `throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';` inside your json response?

Comment: This is **not** a valid JSON.  Fix the code.

Comment: So fetch it as a string, remove first line, parse the string to make it an object.

Comment: Looks like a prefix to prevent JSON hijacking?

Comment: @swonder just like how people put an infinite loop there.....

Comment: This is what I am getting as a response from a third party api called JIVE when I hit the request. @swonder

Comment: You are receiving a **string**.  Removethis line **before** parsing it to an Object.

Comment: Wonderful what you can find searching on the web for "JIVE throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';". It's amazing how editors document their product, really !

Comment: @SiddharthThakor Are you sure that this is the exact response you get? If not, please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
:

```
const prefix = "throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';";
response = response.substring(prefix.length);
```

Due to [this information](https://community.jivesoftware.com/community/developer/blog/2015/06/29/throw-allowillegalresourcecall-to-the-curb-is-true) you should use something like this:

> Jive is looking into migration paths to allow us to remove this line from our API allowing the response to be pure JSON once again.

```
let jsonOffset = response.indexOf('{');
response = response.substring(jsonOffset);
```

Comment: That will certainly get rid of the `throw`, but the content will fail in `JSON.parse()`. *edit* the OP may have incorrectly stripped quotes from the property names; the API documentation contains examples that are all proper JSON.

Comment: @Pointy True, but I have no idea why the response would look like this. Maybe possible to "repair" the JSON using a regex.